# Problems using Sweet alert with php query(update)

Tags: javascript, php

okay guys this is an update to be more accurate with out placing the script in a loop

```
<?php....
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result_set)){?>

    ......

        <a href='#' id='<?php echo $row[0];?>'onClick="processDelete(this.id)">Delete</a>
```

above is the code for calling the function to be pass to javascript

onclick process this id that is pointing to the tag id then processed to the script

next the below code is the delete process

```
<script>

    function processDelete(id){
     swal({
    title:"delete",
    text:"do you want to delete it?",
    showCancelButton:True,
    confirmButtonText:"Yes,Sir!",
    cancelButtonText:"Nah still Need it",
    closeOnConfirm: true
    },


      function()
         {
       window.location.href="delete.php?delete_id="+id;
    }

                })
    }
</script>
```

> so maybe next time i gonna post it with Codeigniter or Laravel 5 so
>   rate comment and thnx for reading

Comment: You have an error on your html, it should be like this inside the button: onClick="processDelete()"

Comment: tnx for pointing it out